# Understanding of planes in NAryMatIterator

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have 3-dimension matrix:

```
const int n_mat_size = 5;
const int n_mat_sz[] = { n_mat_size , n_mat_size, n_mat_size };
cv::Mat m1(3, n_mat_sz, CV_32FC1);
```

Now I'd like to iterate its planes and expect that it should be three two-dimensional matrices:

```
const cv::Mat* arrays[] = { &m1, 0 };
cv::Mat planes[3];
cv::NAryMatIterator it(arrays, planes);
std::cout << it.nplanes << ", " << it.planes[0].rows << ", " << it.planes[0].cols;
```

I expect to get output "3, 5, 5", but instead I get "1, 1, 125". Where is the slice of matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the matrix `m1` is continuous, there is only one plane (or slice).

Please refer to the documentation for [`NAryMatIterator`](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/2.4/d5/dd2/classcv_1_1NAryMatIterator.html#details):

> It iterates through the slices (or planes), not the elements, where "slice" is a continuous part of the arrays.

For example, the matrix `m2` in the following code is not continuous:

```
const int n_mat_size = 5;
const int n_mat_sz[] = { n_mat_size , n_mat_size, n_mat_size };
cv::Mat m1(3, n_mat_sz, CV_32FC1);

// Get plane 2 and 3 of m1
// and row 2, row 3 and row 4 of every selected plane
// m2 is not continuous
cv::Mat m2 = m1(cv::Range(2,4), cv::Range(2,5));

const cv::Mat* arrays[] = { &m2, 0 };
cv::Mat planes[3];
cv::NAryMatIterator it(arrays, planes);
std::cout << it.nplanes << ", " << it.planes[0].rows << ", " << it.planes[0].cols << std::end;
```

The output of the above code is: `2, 1, 15`.

Note that the number of rows of every plane is always 1 and the number of columns is the number of elements contained in the plane.

There is a statement:

```
planes[i] = Mat(1, (int)size, A.type(), A.data);
```

in the function `void NAryMatIterator::init`, which can be found at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L4596 .

The above statement sets the size of the plane.

---

To separate the matrix you gave into planes, you could use `cv::InputArray::getMatVector`.

The following code shows it usage.

```
int main()
{
  const int n_mat_size = 3;
  const int n_mat_sz[] = { n_mat_size , n_mat_size, n_mat_size };
  cv::Mat m1(3, n_mat_sz, CV_8U);

  cv::MatIterator_<uchar> it = m1.begin<uchar>();
  cv::MatIterator_<uchar> end = m1.end<uchar>();
  for (uchar i = 0; it != end; ++it, ++i)
  {
         *it = i;
  }

  cv::InputArray arr(m1);
  std::vector<cv::Mat> planes;
  arr.getMatVector(planes);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < planes.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "-------" << std::endl
    << planes[i] << std::endl << "******" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
-------
[  0,   1,   2;
   3,   4,   5;
   6,   7,   8]
******
-------
[  9,  10,  11;
  12,  13,  14;
  15,  16,  17]
******
-------
[ 18,  19,  20;
  21,  22,  23;
  24,  25,  26]
```

### ******

Maybe the easiest one is to use the method `cv::Mat::row(int)`. The corresponding code is:

```
int main()
{
  const int n_mat_size = 3;
  const int n_mat_sz[] = { n_mat_size , n_mat_size, n_mat_size };
  cv::Mat m1(3, n_mat_sz, CV_8U);

  cv::MatIterator_<uchar> it = m1.begin<uchar>();
  cv::MatIterator_<uchar> end = m1.end<uchar>();
  for (uchar i = 0; it != end; ++it, ++i)
  {
         *it = i;
  }

  int n = m1.size[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
     cv::Mat three_d_plane = m1.row(i);
     // three_d_plane has a size 1x3x3
     // std::cout supports only 2-d matrix. Therefore, we change it to 2-d here
     cv::Mat two_d_plane(three_d_plane.size[1], three_d_plane.size[2], three_d_plane.type(), three_d_plane.data);
     std::cout << two_d_plane << std::endl << "----" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The output is

```
[  0,   1,   2;
   3,   4,   5;
   6,   7,   8]
----
[  9,  10,  11;
  12,  13,  14;
  15,  16,  17]
----
[ 18,  19,  20;
  21,  22,  23;
  24,  25,  26]
----
```

Comment: It's insane no one thought to note inside the documentation the fact that each plane is always flattened into a vector.